# How do I determine the date of an account in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display the age of an account by getting when it was made and minusing it by the current date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def age
    created = user.created_at
    today = Date.today
    age = created - today 
end
```

This is in my model, I'm not sure if I can literally take away a date by a date or if my syntax is completely wrong. Any help at all would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think, there are two ways to solve your case:
1) If you need just years/days/etc, for example, years, you don't need to define variable:

```
def age 
  Time.now.year - Time.at(@user.created_at).year #Time.at() I use there, cause, at Default rails set this field like timestamp, if you was changed this, just remove Time.at
end
```

2. If you want to get full info, like years and days and hours, you can do it like:

```
 def age
  created_at = Time.at(@user.created_at)
  today = Time.now
  {
    years: (today.year - created_at.year),
    months: (today.month - created_at.month),
    days: (today.day - created_at.day),
    hours: (today.hour - created_at.hour)
  }
end
```

Here I use `@user` cause it is often used method

```
def set_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id] #for example
end
```

You also can define method `age` like `def age(user)` and next use `user.created_at`.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of that is ok, except you have to work with the same class.

user.created_at is a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Date.today is a Date (no time)

If you do Time.now - user.created_at, you should get a useable number (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

`created_at` is a DateTime, so you should set `today` to be a DateTime as well

```
today = Time.now
```

The difference will be seconds so to get number of days,

```
(today - created_at) / 60 / 60 / 24
```

You should also consider the TimeDifference gem which facilitates calculating diffrerences between times.

https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
def age_in_hours(user)
  origin = user.created_at
  today = Time.now
  hours_from = ((today - origin)/3600).round
end
```